# how i get this tree view nodes inside a task in C#

Tags: c#, .net, task

i have the following method which i get a tree view by root parent in json but it is taking too long, how i change this to inside a task, i tried many things, but always get an exception like InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command that must be closed first.

```
 public JsonResult GetTreeContasContabeis()
    {
        var rootItens = new List<ContaContabil>();
        var allCounts = UnitOfWork.ContasContabeis.All();


        rootItens = allCounts.Where(x => x.ContaContabilPai.Id == null).ToList();


        var retorno = new List<TreeViewRetorno>();

        foreach (var item in rootItens)
            retorno.Add(GetItemContaContabil(item));

        retorno.OrderBy(p => p.text);

        return Json(retorno);
    }


 private TreeViewRetorno GetItemContaContabil(ContaContabil contaContabil)
    {
        var item = new TreeViewRetorno();
        item.id = contaContabil.Id;
        item.text = $"{contaContabil.NumeroConta} - {contaContabil.DescricaoConta}";
        item.hasChildren = (contaContabil.ContasFilhas != null && contaContabil.ContasFilhas.Any());
        item.isTipo = contaContabil.TipoClassificacaoContaContabil;
        item.items = new List<TreeViewRetorno>();

        if (item.hasChildren == true)
        {
            foreach (var filha in contaContabil.ContasFilhas)
                item.items.Add(GetItemContaContabil(filha));
        }
        return item;
    }

 public class TreeViewRetorno
    {
        public Guid? id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public bool hasChildren {get;set;}
        public TipoClassificacaoContaContabil isTipo { get; set; }
        public List<TreeViewRetorno> items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: - Why are you using `dynamic`? You could very easily define the object you're creating. - Why are you calling two consecutive `OrderBy`s? The first one will be ignored. - Why are you calling `OrderBy` on `retorno` and doing nothing with the result?

Comment: does it make sense,  i create a object instead using dynamic, and remove order by

Comment: If it will be an `object` you won't be able to get its `text` property. If you need to do that, just define the class.